# Impossible to use the Package Center after upgrading DSM

Tags: synology, dsm

I have just updated the DSM of a Synology Nas. DSM 5.2-5644 Update 
2.

It seems now I can no longer use the Package center. But, as I have not used the Package Center for a long time, I'm not 100% the issue is related to this DSM upgrade.

When selecting sections like Utilities, Security, Backup or even Community, I get the error message `Connection failed. Please check your network settings` after a long time of "Loading..." turning wheel.

I checked my firewall settings, and allowed every ports and protocols...
But that is not sufficient, since I still have the same error.

Any idea what I should check ? because the error message doesn't give me lots of information.

Comment: What did Synology support say?

Comment: @Stephane Roland, have you checked system Logs for more info? Look under Main menu, Log Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has disappeared as soon as I installed `DSM 5.2-5644 Update 3` a few days later.

So it really seems like an update-related issue, that's been fixed fast.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me. After upgrade it defaults to DHCP and changes it's IP address.  Check your DHCP reservations and you'll find the device in the list. Connect to the web interface on that new IP and reconfigure it to use the DNS reserved IP you've been using in the past.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was a bit different.   I had installed the DNS package, but the DNS was disabled after an OS update.   I had (stupidly) pointed the Synology configuration, under Network / General / Preferred DNS server, to the Synology DNS, not the external DNS.  Since the Synology DNS was offline, it caused the connectivity problem (even though the network interfaces themselves pointed to the external DNS).

Changing the Preferred DNS back to the external DNS fixed the connection problem, and the package system started working again.