# Parts of Synology down or a local issue?

Tags: internet, connection, synology

I have a Synology NAS DS214+ appliance, which lately has started working wierdly.

I started looking into this, after seeing problem with Synology Package Center, same as in this question: [Impossible to use the Package Center after upgrading DSM](https://serverfault.com/questions/748039/impossible-to-use-the-package-center-after-upgrading-dsm)

However, as I tried to browse Synology support forums, I found out that I can't access [forum.synology.com](https://forum.synology.com/) (Connection failed), nor I can see anything in the Synology official website support https://account.synology.com/support/support_form.php . I get:

[image: Synology partially down]

However, I seem to recall that I had this issue with Package Center some weeks ago as well when I just ignored it for the time being, and I wondered if really their support/update webs could be down for THAT long.

At the same time the rest of Internet seems to work OK for me, and the Synology DSM update checker apparently does connect and confirm I have the latest version of DSM for my NAS. I can also connect to [www.synology.com](http://www.synology.com) and even download packages for my model from there.

Since the support forums are down, I can't ask there, so I have decided to bring it here, if anyone knows if there is something going on with Synology, or whether there is something wrong with my Internet connection.

Comment: Both the forum and the support form works perfectly from here. Could it be that you are using the Synology as your local recursive DNS server, and the problems with your NAS is also causing this?

Comment: @EsaJokinen Thank you. No, I am no using Synology as DNS server at all, but I will dig into DNS issues.